# How to make jquery like function to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, syntax-error

I can't figure out what is wrong with the following code. I am trying to achieve jquery like functionality but following code does not work for me. I can see that console.log(dome) prints all the paragraphs in dome array but when i call this array it does not show up any results. Can you please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
<script>
function uquery(domElement){

    console.log("In uquery function");      
    var uqObject={} // end object   

    uqObject.css=function(property, value){

        var dome = document.getElementsByTagName(domElement);

        console.log(dome);
        console.log(property, value);
        console.log(dome.length);               
        for(i=0; i<dome.length; i++ ){

            console.log("loop count"+i);

            if(property=="color")
            {               
                dome[i].style.color=value;              
            }

        }//end loop

    }

    return uqObject; 

}// end uquery

uquery("p").css("color", "red");
//var obj=uquery("p");  
//obj.css("color", "red");


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Testing Jquery like style</p>

    <p>See if it works</p>

    <p>Third Paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to be like jQuery, but you apparently forgot about `$.ready()`, since your problem is the same as trying to use jQuery outside that.

Comment: @PM77-1 He calls it right after the definition.

Comment: @Barmar - Yep. Missed that.

Comment: @Barmar So, it means my javascript is being called before DOM is loading?

Comment: Exactly right. It's being called as soon as it reaches `uquery("p").css("color", "red")` in the script, which is before the `<body>` tag. If you put the script at the end of the body instead of before it, it would work.

Comment: Also can anybody clarify if uqObject.css=function(property, value){} is called a closure? i.e it is a function which can not be directly accessed by outside functions and remembers the variables passed to parent function uquery()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the function after the elements are added to the dom, like on the window.onload event

```
window.onload = function () {
    uquery("p").css("color", "red");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xhWe4/)

Also have a look at the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access the dynamic properties

```
dome[i].style[property] = value;
```